# Dynamic data from ViewBag on Partial View rendered on _Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here I have a partial view in MVC 5

```
@modelType HOA5.MainMenuModel

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="mainNavbar">
    <div class="container">
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlstr)
    </div>
</div>
```

...and the controller returns some dynamic content to ViewBag

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim vModal As New MainMenuModel
    vModal.MenuHTML = SB.ToString
    Dim MenuHTML As String = ReturnMenu()
    ViewBag.htmlstr = MenuHTML
    Return View("MainMenuView")
End Function
```

... and then run just that view

```
http://localhost:52735/mainMenu/
```

It works perfectly and inserts the dynamic content. However, when I add the partial view to _Layout

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/MainMenu/MainMenuView.vbhtml")
```

and run it

```
http://localhost:52735
```

Then the static content appears, but not the dynamic content.. Have also tried variants of @RenderAction, @RenderPartial but either that is not correct, or I have messed up the syntax!

Any pointers would be appreciated as head has been introduced to wall too many times today :-)

Thank you

Comment: try @Html.Partial("MainMenuView") or  move the view to /Shared and try it

Comment: Hi Mate (now I feel that I am back in the UK) - tried a number of variations and the full path was the only thing that returned the view without an error - however I did find a method without a Partial View that works and posted it below. Thank you for replying

Comment: `@Html.Partial()` does not call your controller method - its just renders the html based on the model you pass to it (and you have not passed a model!). Use `@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", controllerName); }` to call the method and return the html (and the method should return a `PartialView()`, not `View()`)

Answer (score -1):

As is so often we make things more complicated :-)

The easy fix was to make the function that returns the HTML string an ActionResult

```
 Function ReturnMainMenu() As ActionResult
        Try
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
            Using DS As DataSet = ReturnDataSet_Data(strSQL, 2, False)
                For Each row As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows

                Next
            End Using
            Dim vModal As New MainMenuModel
            Dim SB As New StringBuilder
            SB.Append("<div class=""navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"" id=""mainNavbar"">")
            SB.Append("<div class=""container"">")
            SB.Append("<div class=""navbar-header"">")
            SB.Append("<button type=""button"" class=""navbar-toggle"" data-toggle=""collapse"" data-target="".navbar-collapse"">")
            SB.Append("<span class=""icon-bar""></span>")
            SB.Append("<span class=""icon-bar""></span>")
            SB.Append("<span class=""icon-bar""></span>")
            SB.Append("</button>")
            SB.Append("<a class=""navbar-brand"" href=""/"">Add Variable Here xxx</a>") ' Add the variable here
            SB.Append("</div>") ' End of navbar-header

            SB.Append("<div class=""navbar-collapse collapse"">")
            SB.Append("<ul class=""nav navbar-nav"">")
            SB.Append("<li><a href=""/"">Home</a></li></li>")
            SB.Append(" <li><a href=""/eInvoice"">Upload eInvoice</a></li>")
            SB.Append("<li><a href=""/ContactUs"">Contact</a></li>")
            SB.Append("</ul>")
            SB.Append("</div>") 'end of navbar-collapse
            SB.Append("</div>")
            SB.Append("</div>")
            Dim checkstring As String = SB.ToString


            vModal.MenuHTML = SB.ToString

            Return Content(checkstring)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Then (now I understand the syntax) add it to _Layout

```
@Html.Action("ReturnMainMenu", "MainMenu")
```

...and everything works....